# What are the security concerns for not installing ssl certificate in spring boot application which runs behind a azure APIM?

Tags: spring-boot, ssl, https, azure-api-management

I have a spring boot application which runs on Azure Kubernetes Service and it exposes a private IP, using this IP I have configured this API on Azure API Manager. All the traffic will be coming to this spring boot application via API manager. Client to APIM connection is secured with SSL certificate coming from azure API manager. But from API manager to back end API application is not secured it is plain http. Is there any security issues for this architecture?

Comment: According to apim official docs, it seems that you can [use azure ad](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-protect-backend-with-aad) to protect the your backend api. https://i.stack.imgur.com/6E1xd.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your situation, since you already use SSL certificate to protect your APIM, I think the architecture is no problem even though there isn't any security configuration between APIM and backend api. APIM will not expose your backend, so others can't get your backend IP or backend url according to the APIM. So I think you do not need to add any other security configuration for your architecture.

For the comment about Azure AD mentioned by Tiny, you can also use Azure AD to protect your api or APIM, but I think it is unnecessary.